# How does JVM handle references to an object that is then set to a new object value using new keyword

Tags: java, pointers, jvm

I'm curious about what happens to java object references that are passed through a method param, set to a class scoped variable in the class where the method lives, and then the original object passed as a param is set to a new value using the new keyword.

My understanding is that objects are passed by reference not value in method params, but what happens in the case when the original object is set to a new value using = new? Does java create a new location in memory for this new object so that pointers to the existing object remain in tact?

Hope I'm not asking a dumb question. - Duncan

Comment: *" but what happens in the case when the original object is set to a new value using = new? Does java create a new location in memory for this new object so that pointers to the existing object remain in tact?*" - Essentially, yes

Comment: Original object still exists, but there is no reference to it and therefore flagged for collection for the next garbage collection. The simple version^

Comment: Java is **always** pass by value. The value of any non-primitive type **is-a** reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass Objects and you can't set Objects.

You only have primitives and references.

A references is an address, typically a 4-byte value like an `int`

So when you change a reference it is no different to setting an `int` value to something else.  In fact, setting a reference to `null` can be exactly the same as setting an int to `0`

> Does java create a new location in memory for this new object so that pointers to the existing object remain in tact?

When you create a new object, new memory is always used.  This will happen even if the old object no longer used anywhere else.